# (iis) route returning blue screen

Tags: reactjs, iis, webdeploy

I have a react application, and I went to upload it to the local company's server in IIS, but when I try to access the route, a blue screen comes back

below I will leave the screen that shows the routing index, the iss configuration and the web.config

[image: error screen]

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
 <rules>
 <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url=".*" />
 <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
 </rule>
 </rules>
 </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './Global.css';
import Home from './Pages/Home';
import { BrowserRouter, Navigate, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Single } from './Pages/Single/single';
import { Login } from './Pages/Login/login';


import { isAuthentic } from './functions/auth';
// const routeServer = ''
const routeServer = '/sac'


async function renderApp() {
  const Authentic = await isAuthentic();
  console.log(Authentic);

  ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path={routeServer + "/"} exact element={Authentic ? <Home /> : <Navigate to={routeServer + '/login'} />} />
          <Route path={routeServer + '/single'} element={Authentic ? <Single /> : <Navigate to={routeServer + '/login'} />} />
          <Route path={routeServer + '/login'} exact element={<Login />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
}

renderApp();
```

auth:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const isAuthentic = async () => {
    let currentPath = window.location.pathname;
    const routeServer = '/sac';

    console.log('authentic ',currentPath);

    if (currentPath !== routeServer + '/login'){
        const data = localStorage.getItem('token');
        if (!data) {
            window.location.href = routeServer + '/login';
            return;
        }
    try {
        const datajson = JSON.parse(data);
        const token = datajson.token;
        const expirationDate = {
            day: datajson.expirationDate.day,
            month: datajson.expirationDate.month
        };


        if (!token) {
            window.location.href = routeServer + '/login';
            return;
        }

        const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/auth', { token, expirationDate });
        if (response.data === 'token invalid') {
            localStorage.removeItem('token');
            window.location.href = routeServer + '/login';
            return;
        }

        return true;

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Erro ao verificar autenticação:', error);
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
        window.location.href =routeServer + '/login';
   }
}
};
```

[pool de aplicativos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJktB.png)

[config site iis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJl4z.png)

link from the repository: https://github.com/leonardohenri/Sac-confina-frontend

Comment: That looks suspiciously like the IIS default homepage but the welcome to IIS image is broken? (View source on the webpage to confirm is it your app or the default file from IIS being displayed)

Comment: Did you get any error messages? Use the F12 developer tools to check if there are any relevant error messages in the console.